# Magento Create api user and assign its role programmatically [SOAP]

Tags: api, magento, magento-1.7, roles

In magento I want to create soap api user by code .
Also assign its role programmatically .
Will create on event observer .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your role from admin .
Check its ID after successful creation .
Add this code according to your requirements :

```
$userapi = Mage::getModel('api/user')
    ->setData(array(
    'username' => 'server@server.com',
    'firstname' => 'nikhil',
    'lastname' => 'ravindran',
    'email' => 'server@server.com',
    'api_key' => 'myp@ssw0rd',
    'api_key_confirmation' => 'myp@ssw0rd',
    'is_active' => 1,
    'user_roles' => '',
    'assigned_user_role' => '',
    'role_name' => '',
    'roles' => array(1) // your created custom role
    ));
$userapi->save();
$userapi->setRoleIds(array(1))  // your created custom role
    ->setRoleUserId($userapi->getUserId())
    ->saveRelations();
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: `'api_key'` and `'api_key_confirmation'` would not work for me. Instead I did `$userapi->setApiKey($apikey)`

Comment: I have been writing custom plugin to expose more SOAP API. As of now have to manually create role, select resources and assign role to user.

How can that be achieved when user is installing the plugin? Basically I want to reduce the manual intervention.

Comment: How can we do this operation in transaction? What if there is a failure saving relationship? Ideally everything should get rollback